# System.Xml.XmlException 'Data at the root level is invalid, line 1, position 1' error is showing up when i changed from 1 xml file to 5

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

Hello everyone recently i have been making a c# app to read a xml file and it worked but now i was tasked with making it do that and read certain nodes from multiple xml files inside a certain folder and now i doesen´t work and shows that error in the title.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
namespace XmlReaderConsoleAPP
{
    class Program
    {
       
        static void Main()
        {
            ProcessFile(@"C:\XMLFiles\SaintGobain_Pam_20210118.xml");
            try
            {
               
                var path = @"C:\XMLFiles\SaintGobain_Pam_20210118.xml";
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);

                foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
                {
                   
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
             catch(Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Erro: {0}", ex.Message);
                return;
            }

            static void ProcessFile(string Filename)
            {
                XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
                xml.LoadXml(Filename);
                XmlNodeList xnLista = xml.SelectNodes(@"//ImportSession/Batches/batch/Documents/Document/Pages/Page");
                Console.WriteLine($"Selected {xnLista.Count} nodes");
                int i = 0;

                foreach (XmlNode xn in xnLista)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine($"{++i} {xn.Name}: {xn.Attributes["ImportFileName"].Value}");



                }

                XmlNodeList xnLista2 = xml.SelectNodes(@"//IndexFields/IndexField");
                Console.WriteLine($"Selected {xnLista2.Count} nodes");
               int j = 0;
                foreach (XmlNode xn in xnLista2)
                {


                    Console.WriteLine($"{++j} {xn.Name}: {xn.Attributes["Value"].Value}");

                    //string error = xn.Attributes["ErrorMessage"]?.Value;
                    //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
                    //{



                    //}

                    //elsex
                    //{


                    //}
                }
                Console.WriteLine(Filename);
            }

           
        }
    }
}
```

If you guys find the error help me out cause i need it.
Ps: the xml files follow the same roots ImportSession/Batches/Batch/Documents/Document/Pages/Page

Comment: The structure of the program seems a little off. You may want to draw the ProcessFile method out of the main method (if this isn't just copy&paste error). Then, you seem to process the same file twice. Once hard-coded and then again in the loop (I'd advise to use EnumerateFiles, btw). Inside the loop, though, nothing happens? Not quite right, I guess.

Comment: @Fildor It's even worse than that, OP is only processing the file once, the entire loop is meaningless here as there is an issue inside the XML which hasn't been provided.

Comment: @Tiago Please check your code, debug it slowly, line by line. Also check the content of the file you specify on line 1, I don't think it is valid XML

Comment: @DavidG _"Inside the loop, though, nothing happens? Not quite right, I guess."_ - I was aware of that. :)

Comment: @Fildor You said OP is processing the file twice, I was just saying that's not true.

Comment: @DavidG I get it. I was in the flow of writing. I should have said "You _would_ process twice - if the loop did what we'd expect it to" or something along that line. I just then realized after having finished that part that the loop is empty, so went on to write the next sentence about that. Sorry to have caused confusion.

Comment: Guys i made it work and it now shows everything i need @Fildor i made a comment on your answer if you can please answer it.

Comment: @Fildor If you can please check this out i would appreciate it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65843719/what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-this-insert-stored-procedure-in-c-sharp-console-app

Comment: @Fildor if you find i redeemed myself also in this question please up it so i can get back to questioning and possible start commentings some post almost at 50 rep

Comment: @DavidG please see my answer and tell me if i was able to explain what i did to fix it right or should i add anything more

Comment: @DavidG please check again and give me some info on if i did it well this time appreciate it

Comment: @Fildor tell me if its better now pls

Comment: Give me a second, I'll have a look.

Comment: thanks man @Fildor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem with objects and their serialization.
You can find a way to do it with these two posts:

Objects:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/objects

Objects serialization:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/how-to-serialize-an-object

Giving some more context.

Start by making empty strings at the start of the method you're doing, it being a foreach loop or a if statement

```
class Program
{
    static DataAccess da = new DataAccess();

    public static void Main()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ImportSession));

        foreach (string filename in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Properties.Settings.Default.PastaXML, "*.xml"))
        {
            string fName = "";
            string BatchCName = "";
            string batchName = "";
            string description = "";

            ProcessFile(filename, serializer, fName, BatchCName, batchName, description );
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

After that start in my case my `processfile` function

```
private static void ProcessFile(string filename, XmlSerializer serializer, string fName, string batchName, string description, string BatchCName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A processar xml: " + filename);
        bool temErro = false;
       
        using (FileStream file = File.OpenRead(filename))
        {
            var session = (ImportSession)serializer.Deserialize(file);
     
            foreach (Batch batch in session.Batches)
            {
                fName = Path.GetFileName(filename);
                BatchCName = batch.BatchClassName;
                batchName = batch.Name;
                description = batch.Description;
                foreach (Document doc in batch.Documents)
                {
                    foreach (Page page in doc.Pages)
                    {
            @            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(batch.Processed.ToString()))
                        {
                            if (page.HasError)
                            {
                               
                                string Import = page.ImportFileName;
                                Console.WriteLine("Página com erro:" + Import + fName);
                                temErro = true;                                
                                da.SP_Insert(filename,fName,BatchCName,batchName,description,1,Import,0, "");
```

There are two if statements inside this processfile that run checks on if there is a error inside the file and if the file as already been processed.

I also added Insert into a stored procedure to make sure everything is complete in this edit I'm making.

The objects I used are as follows

```
public class ImportSession
{
    public Batch[] Batches { get; set; }
}

public class Batch
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string BatchClassName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public bool Processed { get; set; }
    public Document[] Documents { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string FormTypeName { get; set; }
    public IndexField[] IndexFields { get; set; }
    public Page[] Pages { get; set; }
}

public class IndexField
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ImportFileName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool HasError => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ErrorMessage);
}
```

And my stored procedure insert in case any of you are wondering how to do it

```
public void SP_Insert(string XMLPath, string XMLName, string BatchClassName, string BatchName,
        string BatchDescription, int Error, string ErrorImagePath, int Done, string DonePath)
    {

        try
        {
            ManageConnectionState();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Sp_Insert", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add("@XMLPath",SqlDbType.NText).Value = XMLPath;
            command.Parameters.Add("@XMLName",SqlDbType.NText).Value = XMLName;
            command.Parameters.Add("@BatchClassName",SqlDbType.NText).Value= BatchClassName;
            command.Parameters.Add("@BatchName",SqlDbType.NText ).Value = BatchName;
            command.Parameters.Add("@BatchDescription", SqlDbType.NText ).Value = BatchDescription;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Error",SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Error;
            command.Parameters.Add("@ErrorImagePath", SqlDbType.NText).Value = ErrorImagePath;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Done", SqlDbType.Bit ).Value=Done;
            command.Parameters.Add("@DonePath", SqlDbType.NText).Value = DonePath;
            command.ExecuteScalar();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Erro: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            ManageConnectionState();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Please comment if you don´t understand something ill help out.

Comment: Nice, you put a lot of effort in this. There are still some minor formatting issues, I'll have a look at those, maybe you can correct, too. For the first two snippets: I don't get why you need so many function arguments. As far as I can see you'd only need serializer and filename. The rest of those args, you could create as local vars inside the function that's being called.

Comment: @Fildor ye i kinda did but when i got a grasp of what i was doing and with the help of you and other i kinda just rolled with it and it ended working and please tell me how i can improve it

Comment: Ok, so `ProcessFile` in fact only needs `private static void ProcessFile(string filename, XmlSerializer serializer)` . Then you can move `string fName = ""; ... string description = "";` inside `ProcessFile` method. Just make those the first lines inside the function.

Comment: @Fildor i don´t want to say your wrong but wont that change the way my dataAccess file is made since i have processfile being called from there and i have all the variables comming from them

Comment: Nope. All those are set inside the function. As far as I can see from the code in your answer, here.

Comment: ill edit the answer and put up the process file on the dataAccess ps:its not called processfile its my sp insert. Edited

Answer (score 1):

Let's first clean up a little:

```
namespace XmlReaderConsoleAPP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
                var path = @"C:\XMLFiles";
                var filter = @"*.xml"; // Add filter to only enumerate .xml files

                foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, filter))
                {
// Move try/catch inside the loop to skip errornous files.
                   try
                   {
                       ProcessFile( file );
                   }
                   catch(Exception ex) // Usually, try to catch the specific as possible
                   {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0} {1}in File {2}", 
                                            ex.Message, Environment.NewLine, file);
                   }
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        } // End of Main

            static void ProcessFile(string Filename)
            {
                XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
                xml.LoadXml(Filename);
                XmlNodeList xnLista = xml.SelectNodes(@"//ImportSession/Batches/batch/Documents/Document/Pages/Page");
                Console.WriteLine($"Selected {xnLista.Count} nodes");
                int i = 0;

                foreach (XmlNode xn in xnLista)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{++i} {xn.Name}: {xn.Attributes["ImportFileName"].Value}");
                }

                XmlNodeList xnLista2 = xml.SelectNodes(@"//IndexFields/IndexField");
                Console.WriteLine($"Selected {xnLista2.Count} nodes");
               int j = 0;
                foreach (XmlNode xn in xnLista2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{++j} {xn.Name}: {xn.Attributes["Value"].Value}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine(Filename);
            }
           
    } // class
} // namespace
```

Next: `System.Xml.XmlException` means there is something wrong with the xml input file.

What can you do about that?

- Skip it, so the others may still be processed. Log the error, so you can later deep dive into the file, or request it be fixed and sent again.
- If you have an XML Schema, you can *validate* the xml and easier find what exactly is wrong. See [XML schema (XSD) validation with XmlSchemaSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xml-schema-xsd-validation-with-xmlschemaset) and/or [XmlDocument.Validate Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.validate?view=net-5.0).
- You can examine the input file manually and find the error. Mind that the message may sometimes be deceiving. I'd start with checking if it is well-formed and valid xml (there are tools for that).

Comment: Hello Fildor i made it work now it shows everything i needed but guess what now i need to make it as if it only shows information that as specific info in them such as the error and if on the batch node it as Processed = to 1 is it possible for you to help me with it as well? ps: You have been a great help .

Comment: Sure, just post a new question with updated code and new requirements and we'll see where your problem with that is.